# Multistate rules design strategy

Tags: java, resourcebundle

I need to implement logic that vary from one state to another.
I am planning to have separate classes for each state containing state specific logic. I am planning to use ResourceBundle to load the version of implementation I need.

For example,

- Class.java
- Class-CA.java
- Class-AZ.java etc

How can I effectively stop my developers to use "`new Class()`" in their code and to always use the resourcebundle to load the appropriate class version?

Answer (score 1):

If you give `Class` a private constructor then no one can instantiate one.

Combine this with a [Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_%28object-oriented_programming%29) and you can return whichever `Class` or derivative thereof you want.